# SharePoint Online external Sharing with b2c

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

I need some help to understand if SharePoint online can be share externally using B2C **(provides business-to-customer identity as a service**). sorry if the question is not clear, I have done a lot of research and it looks like the only time we can share SharePoint externally if we are using B2B. Can someone please confirm this?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, Azure AD B2C can not be implemented with SharePoint Online.

There are two main reasons why Azure AD B2C can't be used to authenticate users for Microsoft Office 365.

1.Microsoft Office 365 authenticates external users by using email accounts that have applied for Microsoft accounts. But with Azure AD B2C, it can use any email accounts and three-party application accounts.

2.For Microsoft Office 365, external users are managed in the same directory as internal employees.  But Azure AD B2C is an independent service for building a consumer application identity repository. It makes external users store in the application directory. So, they are managed separately from the internal employees.

References:

https://predica.pl/blog/azure-ad-b2b-b2c-puzzled-out/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c

Comment: Thanks, Emily. I have read your comments as well as the two links that you have provided. So with your experience and knowledge, if we are using B2C can I share a SharePoint site with someone externally using their Gmail account?

Comment: You could use Anyone link to share with Gmail account.